# Uploading data frame to redshift table through R

Tags: r, postgresql, import, tidyverse, amazon-redshift

I am doing some data manipulation on a csv file and then writing it into a new csv file called "upload_data_now()". Everything works fine but i keep getting an error on the last part where i am trying to upload the data.frame(upload_data) to public.revman table.
[image]

```
#############Import required libraries#############
    library(tidyverse)
    library(lubridate)
    library(stringr)
    library(openxlsx)
    library(RPostgreSQL)
    library(data.table)
    
    #################### Clear environment & set Working Directory #################
    rm(list=ls())
    
    setwd(dirname(rstudioapi::getActiveDocumentContext()$path))
    
    data <- fread("Input Files/FW42CombinedExceptionUpload Template.csv") %>%
      mutate(`site ID` = str_pad(`site ID`, pad = 0, width = 3), ##SRC: THIS STEP WILL TAKE CARE OF ROWS 19-28
             `customer ID` = str_pad(`customer ID`, pad = 0, width = 6),
             co_cust_id = paste0(`site ID`,'-',`customer ID`))
    
    myconn <-dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
                       , read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[5,9]
                       , port=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[6,9]
                       , dbname=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[2,9]
                       , user=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[3,9]
                       , password=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[4,9]
    )
    
    existing_cust <- dbGetQuery(myconn, paste0("SELECT co_cust_id FROM public.revman_initiative_scope WHERE co_cust_id IN ('", paste(unique(data$co_cust_id), collapse = "', '"), "')")) ##SRC: I WRAPPED DATA$CO_CUST_NBR IN A UNIQUE() FUNCTION TO GET DISTINCT VALUES
    
    dbDisconnect(myconn)
    gc()
    
    
    upload_data <- data %>%
      anti_join(existing_cust %>% rename(co_cust_id = co_cust_id)) %>% 
      mutate(initiative_nm = "Hispanic Pricing: New Hispanic Customers", 
             co_skey = as.numeric(`site ID`),
             cust_nbr = as.numeric(`customer ID`),
             updt_user = "sraz2759",
             updt_dttm = Sys.time(),
             supc_pz_id = 0) %>%
      select(initiative_nm 
             , co_skey
             , cust_nbr
             , co_cust_id 
             , updt_user
             , updt_dttm
             , supc_pz_id) %>%
      distinct()
    
    
    ## Write the updated data frame to a new CSV file
    fwrite(upload_data, paste0("Results/upload_data_",today(),".csv")) 
    
    myconn <-dbConnect(dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
                       , read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[5,9]
                       , port=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[6,9]
                       , dbname=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[2,9]
                       , user=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[3,9]
                       , password=read.xlsx("~/sqlp.xlsx", colNames = F)[4,9]
    )
    dbWriteTable(myconn, "public.revman", upload_data, append = TRUE)
    
    dbDisconnect(myconn)
    gc()
```

Comment: side note: I suggest you `read.xlsx` _only once_, then first verify all of the rows/columns are as you expect, then use the already-read-in data for each of our `dbConnect` parameters.

Comment: You may want to consider parameterized queries vice constructing query strings manually. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query. `DBI` supports [parameterized queries](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries); `RODBC` does not (because `RODBCext` has since been removed).

Comment: I wonder if this could be a bug with `RPostgreSQL`, perhaps [here](https://github.com/tomoakin/RPostgreSQL/blob/2f48ac49862a2406bb0e8fc220c8826b989e84be/RPostgreSQL/R/PostgreSQLSupport.R#L659); do you have any non-standard column names that need to be escaped?